# Referencing nsmutablearray to Data Model

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad

I have a design issue which I am trying to analyze in my current project and thought maybe someone could help me figure this out. I have an nsarray object which I filter through predicate, and I want to set that object as my data model through view controller. First, is this a good practice of doing so? Since, I want to have an access of that object through out my transaction. I am not dealing with any database, plist, or core data model at current, these are just custom data model class I have created.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's very common for a view of some sort to be backed by an NSArray, or an NSMutableArray. (Particularly, a `UITableView`, which can provide a single cell for each object in your array.)

Depending on the scope of your project, you can either investigate using Core Data for binding your model to your data:

[**CocoaDevCentral Core Data Overview**](http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000086.php)

Or, for something a bit easier but less robust, you can look into implementing the methods defined in the `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` protocols, if you want to populate the cells of your table on a per-request basis.

Comment: I am using a Singleton Pattern to utilize my global variables, but still I think utilizing this pattern over and over in different view controllers may sound little silly but have a data model that is linked from Singleton, therefore I am keeping MVC model still by populating my data model through singleton once. However, in this scenario since I have an nsmutablearray object, which I want to use globally I don't feel its a good practice to dedicate an array in singleton and again pass it to data model, which I can strictly pass directly at initialization process.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean, and this is indeed the common problem that frameworks like Core Data attempt to alleviate. I would strongly recommend investigating the Core Data Overview link in my answer, specifically the use of NSArrayController, which (as expected) forms the 'C' (controller) in MVC between the model (stored in your singleton) and the view.